# Trying to deploy my selenium with Java on Heroku

Tags: java, selenium, heroku

I am new to Heroku and am trying to deploy my selenium code with java on it. I followed all the prerequisites like having git repo and maven in place i.e pom.xml file. I added headless chrome dependency in Pom.xml file. I am not sure where should ChromeDriver point to interact with chrome.
What does this mean “ You can choose your release channel by specifying GOOGLE_CHROME_CHANNEL as a config var for your app, in your app.json (for Heroku CI and Review Apps), or in your pipeline settings (for Heroku CI).“ from the link: “https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/blob/master/README.md “
 Should I create a JSON file in my java project?

Where can I find this path on ‘/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome’? on Mac?

I am using Mac though. Please help me.